# Convert NSDictionary from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to convert the FBLoginCutomUISample from objective C to swift. So far everything is working fine. I just get stuck at this point:

```
//Get more error information from the error
NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

// Show the user an error message
alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
[self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
```

I tried several solutions such as:

```
if let info = error.userInfo {
    let errorInformation = info["com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"]["body"]["error"]
    let msg = errorInformation["message"]
    println("errormessage: \(msg)")
}
```

But it gives me every time the same error: '(NSObject, AnyObject)' does not have a member named 'subscript'. It seems to be an unwrapping problem but I have no idea how to solve it. Thanks

**[UPDATE SOLUTION]**
From the answer below I can finally update here the working code:

```
if let info = error.userInfo{
    if let dict1 = info["com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let dict2 = dict1["body"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let errorInformation = dict2["error"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let msg:AnyObject = errorInformation["message"] {
                    println("errormessage: \(msg)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Array/dictionary references via `[...]` invoke a "subscript" method on the object.  The compiler does not know what kind of object you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every dictionary lookup in Swift returns an optional that must be unwrapped.  In addition, you might have to use conditional casts `as?` to tell Swift what type to expect.  You might be able to chain multiple dictionary accesses together by using optional chaining following each dictionary lookup with `?`.

Try this:

```
if let info = error.userInfo {
    if let errorInformation = info["com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"]?["body"]?["error"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let msg = errorInformation["message"] {
            println("errormessage: \(msg)")
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to tell Swift at each step that you expect an `NSDictionary`:

```
if let info = error.userInfo {
    if let dict1 = info["com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let dict2 = dict1["body"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let errorInformation = dict2["error"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let msg = errorInformation["message"] {
                    println("errormessage: \(msg)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried both code and it gives me a new error:  "'NSDictionary' is not a subtype of '[NSObject : AnyObject]'". I don't really get why could it be a NSDictionary in objective C and it can't be in Swift. (Sorry I'm beginning with the language)

Comment: Try taking off the `as? NSDictionary` in both places in the first example. Swift apparently already knows it is a dictionary in this case.

Comment: Well in fact it worked for the second example by taking off the "as? NSDictionary" only on the first line. I think Swift already know the type of error.userInfo but not the type inside this Dictionary. Thanks a lot.